# Routing to pages in WordPress based off password entered

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching for a solution that would allow for me to have a front page with just a password prompt field and depending on the password entered, it would route you to specific page on my site.

I've see a few plugins for password protecting your entire site or password protecting at a page-level, but I have been unable to come across anything that would allow for you to set-up multiple password and route people to pages depending on what password is entered.

Is anyone familiar with a plugin or tutorial/example for achieving this?

Comment: If I were to build this, I would make a custom template for the home page, put a form in it and then handle the POST using an `if` or a `switch` statement.